# Why does Intel SpeedStep influence the number of cycles for execution?

Tags: c, visual-studio, intel

I am currently measuring the cycle count for a piece of C code to be executed. The code is executed in an extra thread generated with _beginthreadex() from the Windows API every 10ms. The cycle measurement is made with QueryThreadCycleTimes() to avoid counting ticks of interrupts or something else.

When I execute solely this code on my machine, the cycle count varies between 550 000 and 1 800 000  , each after a few (5-10) calls.

After some research I found out, that with Intel SpeedStep turned off, the cycle count is in median 580 000 with a deviation of around 10 000 ticks. Acceptable!
So my question is now, how can SpeedStep influence the number of cycles needed for execution. As I thought, it only lowers the frequency of the processor by lowering power intake, which should not affect the cycle count, but the time needed to reach this cycle count? Maybe someone knows if there is influence on other important hardware parts or CPU Cache maybe?

Thank you in advance. Greetings 
Sascha

System properties:

Intel Xeon E5 - 1620 Processor

Visual Studio 2013

Comment: QueryThreadCycleTimes does not measure cycles, it measures time.   Speed, power consumption and fan noise are trade-offs.  Maybe you need to get the vacuum cleaner out, open the computer case and suck out the dust bunnies.  Programmers don't do this often enough.

Comment: @Hans Well, then I got that wrong with thread kernel and user cycles on the MSDN Page. Now the relation from lower frequency to higher time consumed is clear. Here [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160429-00/?p=93385) it states that there are usually cycles measured but with the nominal CPU rate. So for lower frequency the cycle counter ticks "too fast". Question is solved, thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QueryThreadCycleTime function [manual page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684943%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states:

> This function uses timer services provided by the CPU, which can vary in implementation. For example, some CPUs will vary the frequency of the timer when changing the frequency at which the CPU runs and others will leave it at a fixed rate. The behavior of each CPU is described in the documentation provided by the CPU vendor.

I tried to find information on how the Intel Xeon processor does, but my search karma wasn't with me.

Comment: All x86 CPUs for a while now have had a constant-rate TSC that doesn't change with clock speed.  This makes it useful as a high-precision low-overhead time source (e.g. POSIX `gettimeofday(2)`), but not as useful for microbenchmarking unless you disable variable-frequency, or give the CPU time to ramp to max frequency first.  perf counters can count actual core clock cycles, but you have to sample them.